# Better way to update custom activities binaries

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Currently I have few `custom activities` in the main `build template`. Each additional `activity` is stored in same `binary` but different `class`. To `update binary` I need to `delete` old one, `check-in delete`, copy manually from `bin folder` to `tfs build controller folder`, `add items` to `source control` and `check in` changes.

I would like to prevent problem of missing custom activities binary from `build template` while doing this process.

Can I do it any other way. So there is no time when `binary` doesn't exist in `source control`.

Comment: What's the meaning of "Each additional activity is stored in same binary but different class"?

Comment: One dll, but on toolbox each is a separate tool. They are just for getting basic data and loading dll's

Comment: I would recommend that you upgrade to TFS 2015 (that does not mean you need VS2015) and use  the new build system rather  than the legacy xaml builds.

Comment: We are upgrading slowly, first bunch of servers need to get updated then tfs and then couple thousands builds. Takes time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily check in the new DLL over the top of the previous one.

If you are using a local Workspace then you just drop the new DLL on top of the old one. This can be automated with a post build script.

If you are using a server workspace (and files are read only) then you will need to check out the file before copying the new one over the top.

You can have an automated build that automated this  entire process.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should have two projects in your solution. One of the projects is for the custom code and custom activities, the other one to modify the build process template.

After you modify the process template, you need to check in process template and custom activities. The custom activities path should have been specified in your build controller.

Check this blog on how to create your own activity: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/customize-team-build-2010-e28093-part-4-create-your-own-activity.aspx

Comment: Thank you but thats exactly what I'm doing right now. I have single custom activity binary and bunch dll that custom activity loads. Uploading them isn't problem so it didn't mention it. It is updating custom activity to source control without time where there is no custom activity dll in source control.